# Mongo DB not updating, without error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, express

Trying to update the below M Lab hosted mongo DB, not much luck, any ideas? Form input via handlebars template, routed to express server. No errors, and DB does not update.

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58fdec20a8aac60a190152ae"
    },
    "name": "Item1",
    "status": 0
}

```js
app.put("/:id", function(req, res) {

    db.collection.update({_id: req.body.id}, 
        {
            $set:{status: 1}, function(){
            res.redirect("/");
            console.log('updated')
            }
    });

});
```

```html
<ul> Let's Eat
  {{#each ndev}}
    <li> 
      <p>
        <form action="/:{{this._id}}?_method=PUT" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{_id}}">{{name}}
          <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>
      </p>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `findOneAndUpdate` method, also pass `{new: true}` to get back updated document

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, you got me on the right track.

Comment: Don't use `findAndModify` you have the `_id` and there would be only one document in database. Use `findOneAndUpdate` method

Answer (score 1):

Please make callback function out of $set braces just like this:

```
app.put("/:id", function(req, res) {
    db.collection.update({_id: req.body.id},{$set:{status: 1}}, function(err,doc)
    {
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
      }
      res.redirect("/");
      console.log('updated')        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mongojs below was my solution.

```js
app.put("/:id", function(req, res) {
    var id = req.body.id; 
    db.collection.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, 
        update: { $set: {status: 1}},
        new: true},
        function(err, doc, collection){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
            }else{
        res.redirect("/");
            }
            });
        });
```